Extend tt_address with a mm_relation (Typo3 12)
I've been trying to extend tt_address with a mm_relation with not much luck so far. Anything I can find online is just for a regular relation, where the ID is saved directly into the same table, not an extra _mm table.
The backend looks fine so far, the way I want it with a selectMultipleSideBySide renderType. It also saves the relations to the database.
Typo3 12.4.16 // TT_Address 8.1.0 // extender 10.1.1
.../extensions/wiwa/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_address.php
<?php
defined('TYPO3') or die();

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility;

(static function () {
    ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_address',
        [
        'product_groups' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:wiwa/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_wiwa_domain_model_product.product_group',
            'description' => 'Auswahl der WIWA-Produktkategorie',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_wiwa_domain_model_productgroup',
                'MM' => 'tt_address_productgroup_mm',                
                'default' => 0,
                'size' => 10,
                'autoSizeMax' => 30,
                'maxitems' => 3,
                'multiple' => true,
                'fieldControl' => [
                    'editPopup' => [
                        'disabled' => false,
                    ],
                    'addRecord' => [
                        'disabled' => false,
                    ],
                    'listModule' => [
                        'disabled' => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
           ],
          ],
    );

    ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
        'tt_address',
        'product_groups',
        '',
        'before:name'
    );
})();        
I followed Extend models of tt_address
.../extensions/wiwa/ext_tables.sql
CREATE TABLE tt_address_productgroup_mm (
    uid_local int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    uid_foreign int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    sorting int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    sorting_foreign int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (uid_local,uid_foreign),
    KEY uid_local (uid_local),
    KEY uid_foreign (uid_foreign)
);
CREATE TABLE tt_address (
    product_groups int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',     
);  

.../extensions/wiwa/Classes/Extending/Domain/Model/Address.php
<<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Replicare\Wiwa\Extending\Domain\Model;

class Address extends \FriendsOfTYPO3\TtAddress\Domain\Model\Address
{

    /**
     * productGroups
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Replicare\Wiwa\Domain\Model\ProductGroup>
     */
    protected $productGroups = null;
    
    /**
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->productGroups = $this->productGroups ?: new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    }    
    
    /**
     * Adds a productGroup
     *
     * @param \Replicare\Wiwa\Domain\Model\ProductGroup $productGroup
     * @return void
     */
    public function addProductGroup(\Replicare\Wiwa\Domain\Model\ProductGroup $productGroup)
    {
        $this->productGroups->attach($productGroup);
    }

    /**
     * Removes a productGroup
     *
     * @param \Replicare\Wiwa\Domain\Model\productGroup $productGroupToRemove The productGroup to be removed
     * @return void
     */
    public function removeProductGroup(\Replicare\Wiwa\Domain\Model\ProductGroup $productGroupToRemove)
    {
        $this->productGroups->detach($productGroupToRemove);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the productGroups
     *
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Replicare\Wiwa\Domain\Model\ProductGroup> $productGroups
     */
    public function getProductGroups()
    {
        return $this->productGroups;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the productGroups
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Replicare\Wiwa\Domain\Model\ProductGroup> $productGroups
     * @return void
     */
    public function setProductGroups(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $productGroups)
    {
        $this->productGroups = $productGroups;
    }

}

Changes in ext_localconf.php are not needed anymore: Changelog extender
and I have configured extender in services.yaml following the instructions in the extender manual.
# Configuration/Services.yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false


    
  Replicare\Wiwa\Extending\Domain\Model\Address:
    tags:
      -
        name: 'extender.extends'
        class: FriendsOfTYPO3\TtAddress\Domain\Model\Address    




The problem I'm having now is getting these relations in my fluid templates. The variable location.product_groups just contains the integer number of related objects, instead of the list of objects.
Extbase Variable Dump
How can I get the product_groups that are associated with that location in fluid, with an m:m relation?

It sounds like your model is not known by fluid. Have you required EXT:extender?

In Composer.json
"require": {
"evoweb/extender": "^10.1",
....

In the composer.json of your wiwa-package? Or the root composer.json? dependencies have to be declared within our concrete package: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FileStructure/ExtEmconf.html

In composer.json of wiwa-package. Ok, I added them to dependencies ..
   'constraints' => [         'depends' => [             'typo3' => '12.0.0-12.4.99',             'extender' => '',             'tt_address' => '', 
deleted cache / readded the database elements, but no difference

I'm pretty sure there is a solution to my problem, but I can't find the problem myself. Is there anyone who can support me? I would also be prepared to pay for help ...
